# Javascript keyup function first keypress don't work two press worked

Tags: javascript, onchange, keyup

My code working but half working :(
The action that needs to be done is to execute various operations on the entered data and to write the collection. However, when the keys are pressed, the previous operation is performed.
Note: format.money and unformat in accounting js.

```js
function inputkopyala(){
    var t = $('#toplam').val();
    if ($('#toplam1').val() == null) {
        var t1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t1 = $('#toplam1').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam2').val() == null) {
        var t2 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t2 = $('#toplam2').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam3').val() == null) {
        var t3 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t3 = $('#toplam3').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam4').val() == null) {
        var t4 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t4 = $('#toplam4').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam5').val() == null) {
        var t5 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t5 = $('#toplam5').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam6').val() == null) {
        var t6 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t6 = $('#toplam6').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam7').val() == null) {
        var t7 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t7 = $('#toplam7').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam8').val() == null) {
        var t8 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t8 = $('#toplam8').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam9').val() == null) {
        var t9 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t9 = $('#toplam9').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam10').val() == null) {
        var t10 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t10 = $('#toplam10').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam11').val() == null) {
        var t11 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t11 = $('#toplam11').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam12').val() == null) {
        var t12 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t12 = $('#toplam12').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam13').val() == null) {
        var t13 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t13 = $('#toplam13').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam14').val() == null) {
        var t14 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t14 = $('#toplam14').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam15').val() == null) {
        var t15 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t15 = $('#toplam15').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam16').val() == null) {
        var t16 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t16 = $('#toplam16').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam17').val() == null) {
        var t17 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t17 = $('#toplam17').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam18').val() == null) {
        var t18 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t18 = $('#toplam18').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam19').val() == null) {
        var t19 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t19 = $('#toplam19').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam20').val() == null) {
        var t20 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t20 = $('#toplam20').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam21').val() == null) {
        var t21 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t21 = $('#toplam21').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam22').val() == null) {
        var t22 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t22 = $('#toplam22').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam23').val() == null) {
        var t23 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t23 = $('#toplam23').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam24').val() == null) {
        var t24 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t24 = $('#toplam24').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam25').val() == null) {
        var t25 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t25 = $('#toplam25').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam26').val() == null) {
        var t26 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t26 = $('#toplam26').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam27').val() == null) {
        var t27 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t27 = $('#toplam27').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam28').val() == null) {
        var t28 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t28 = $('#toplam28').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam29').val() == null) {
        var t29 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t29 = $('#toplam29').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam30').val() == null) {
        var t30 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t30 = $('#toplam30').val();
    }
    var sonuc;
    sonuc = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(t)+accounting.unformat(t1)+accounting.unformat(t2)+accounting.unformat(t3)+accounting.unformat(t4)+accounting.unformat(t5)+accounting.unformat(t6)+accounting.unformat(t7)+accounting.unformat(t8)+accounting.unformat(t9)+accounting.unformat(t10)+accounting.unformat(t11)+accounting.unformat(t12)+accounting.unformat(t13)+accounting.unformat(t14)+accounting.unformat(t15)+accounting.unformat(t16)+accounting.unformat(t17)+accounting.unformat(t18)+accounting.unformat(t19)+accounting.unformat(t20)+accounting.unformat(t21)+accounting.unformat(t22)+accounting.unformat(t23)+accounting.unformat(t24)+accounting.unformat(t25)+accounting.unformat(t26)+accounting.unformat(t27)+accounting.unformat(t28)+accounting.unformat(t29)+accounting.unformat(t30));
    $('#yekun').html(""+sonuc +"");
    var v = $('#vergi').val();
    if ($('#vergi1').val() == null) {
        var v1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v1 = $('#vergi1').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi2').val() == null) {
        var v2 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v2 = $('#vergi2').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi3').val() == null) {
        var v3 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v3 = $('#vergi3').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi4').val() == null) {
        var v4 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v4 = $('#vergi4').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi5').val() == null) {
        var v5 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v5 = $('#vergi5').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi6').val() == null) {
        var v6 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v6 = $('#vergi6').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi7').val() == null) {
        var v7 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v7 = $('#vergi7').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi8').val() == null) {
        var v8 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v8 = $('#vergi8').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi9').val() == null) {
        var v9 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v9 = $('#vergi9').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi10').val() == null) {
        var v10 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v10 = $('#vergi10').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi11').val() == null) {
        var v11 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v11 = $('#vergi11').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi12').val() == null) {
        var v12 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v12 = $('#vergi12').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi13').val() == null) {
        var v13 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v13 = $('#vergi13').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi14').val() == null) {
        var v14 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v14 = $('#vergi14').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi15').val() == null) {
        var v15 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v15 = $('#vergi15').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi16').val() == null) {
        var v16 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v16 = $('#vergi16').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi17').val() == null) {
        var v17 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v17 = $('#vergi17').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi18').val() == null) {
        var v18 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v18 = $('#vergi18').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi19').val() == null) {
        var v19 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v19 = $('#vergi19').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi20').val() == null) {
        var v20 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v20 = $('#vergi20').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi21').val() == null) {
        var v21 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v21 = $('#vergi21').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi22').val() == null) {
        var v22 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v22 = $('#vergi22').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi23').val() == null) {
        var v23 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v23 = $('#vergi23').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi24').val() == null) {
        var v24 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v24 = $('#vergi24').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi25').val() == null) {
        var v25 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v25 = $('#vergi25').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi26').val() == null) {
        var v26 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v26 = $('#vergi26').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi27').val() == null) {
        var v27 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v27 = $('#vergi27').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi28').val() == null) {
        var v28 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v28 = $('#vergi28').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi29').val() == null) {
        var v29 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v29 = $('#vergi29').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi30').val() == null) {
        var v30 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v30 = $('#vergi30').val();
    }
    var vergiler;
    vergiler = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(v)+accounting.unformat(v1)+accounting.unformat(v2)+accounting.unformat(v3)+accounting.unformat(v4)+accounting.unformat(v5)+accounting.unformat(v6)+accounting.unformat(v7)+accounting.unformat(v8)+accounting.unformat(v9)+accounting.unformat(v10)+accounting.unformat(v11)+accounting.unformat(v12)+accounting.unformat(v13)+accounting.unformat(v14)+accounting.unformat(v15)+accounting.unformat(v16)+accounting.unformat(v17)+accounting.unformat(v18)+accounting.unformat(v19)+accounting.unformat(v20)+accounting.unformat(v21)+accounting.unformat(v22)+accounting.unformat(v23)+accounting.unformat(v24)+accounting.unformat(v25)+accounting.unformat(v26)+accounting.unformat(v27)+accounting.unformat(v28)+accounting.unformat(v29)+accounting.unformat(v30));
    $('#topkdv').html(""+vergiler +"");
    document.urunformu.toplam.value = accounting.formatMoney(document.urunformu.adet.value*document.urunformu.birimfiyat.value)
    document.urunformu.vergi.value = accounting.formatMoney(document.urunformu.adet.value*document.urunformu.birimfiyat.value*document.urunformu.vergioran.value/100)
    document.getElementById("geneltoplam").innerHTML = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(document.getElementById("yekun").innerHTML)+accounting.unformat(document.getElementById("topkdv").innerHTML))
}
function inputkopyala1(){
    var t = $('#toplam').val();
    if ($('#toplam1').val() == null) {
        var t1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t1 = $('#toplam1').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam2').val() == null) {
        var t2 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t2 = $('#toplam2').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam3').val() == null) {
        var t3 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t3 = $('#toplam3').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam4').val() == null) {
        var t4 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t4 = $('#toplam4').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam5').val() == null) {
        var t5 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t5 = $('#toplam5').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam6').val() == null) {
        var t6 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t6 = $('#toplam6').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam7').val() == null) {
        var t7 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t7 = $('#toplam7').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam8').val() == null) {
        var t8 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t8 = $('#toplam8').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam9').val() == null) {
        var t9 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t9 = $('#toplam9').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam10').val() == null) {
        var t10 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t10 = $('#toplam10').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam11').val() == null) {
        var t11 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t11 = $('#toplam11').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam12').val() == null) {
        var t12 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t12 = $('#toplam12').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam13').val() == null) {
        var t13 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t13 = $('#toplam13').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam14').val() == null) {
        var t14 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t14 = $('#toplam14').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam15').val() == null) {
        var t15 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t15 = $('#toplam15').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam16').val() == null) {
        var t16 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t16 = $('#toplam16').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam17').val() == null) {
        var t17 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t17 = $('#toplam17').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam18').val() == null) {
        var t18 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t18 = $('#toplam18').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam19').val() == null) {
        var t19 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t19 = $('#toplam19').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam20').val() == null) {
        var t20 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t20 = $('#toplam20').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam21').val() == null) {
        var t21 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t21 = $('#toplam21').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam22').val() == null) {
        var t22 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t22 = $('#toplam22').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam23').val() == null) {
        var t23 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t23 = $('#toplam23').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam24').val() == null) {
        var t24 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t24 = $('#toplam24').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam25').val() == null) {
        var t25 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t25 = $('#toplam25').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam26').val() == null) {
        var t26 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t26 = $('#toplam26').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam27').val() == null) {
        var t27 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t27 = $('#toplam27').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam28').val() == null) {
        var t28 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t28 = $('#toplam28').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam29').val() == null) {
        var t29 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t29 = $('#toplam29').val();
    }
    if ($('#toplam30').val() == null) {
        var t30 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var t30 = $('#toplam30').val();
    }
    var sonuc;
    sonuc = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(t)+accounting.unformat(t1)+accounting.unformat(t2)+accounting.unformat(t3)+accounting.unformat(t4)+accounting.unformat(t5)+accounting.unformat(t6)+accounting.unformat(t7)+accounting.unformat(t8)+accounting.unformat(t9)+accounting.unformat(t10)+accounting.unformat(t11)+accounting.unformat(t12)+accounting.unformat(t13)+accounting.unformat(t14)+accounting.unformat(t15)+accounting.unformat(t16)+accounting.unformat(t17)+accounting.unformat(t18)+accounting.unformat(t19)+accounting.unformat(t20)+accounting.unformat(t21)+accounting.unformat(t22)+accounting.unformat(t23)+accounting.unformat(t24)+accounting.unformat(t25)+accounting.unformat(t26)+accounting.unformat(t27)+accounting.unformat(t28)+accounting.unformat(t29)+accounting.unformat(t30));
    var v = $('#vergi').val();
    if ($('#vergi1').val() == null) {
        var v1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v1 = $('#vergi1').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi2').val() == null) {
        var v2 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v2 = $('#vergi2').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi3').val() == null) {
        var v3 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v3 = $('#vergi3').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi4').val() == null) {
        var v4 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v4 = $('#vergi4').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi5').val() == null) {
        var v5 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v5 = $('#vergi5').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi6').val() == null) {
        var v6 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v6 = $('#vergi6').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi7').val() == null) {
        var v7 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v7 = $('#vergi7').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi8').val() == null) {
        var v8 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v8 = $('#vergi8').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi9').val() == null) {
        var v9 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v9 = $('#vergi9').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi10').val() == null) {
        var v10 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v10 = $('#vergi10').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi11').val() == null) {
        var v11 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v11 = $('#vergi11').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi12').val() == null) {
        var v12 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v12 = $('#vergi12').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi13').val() == null) {
        var v13 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v13 = $('#vergi13').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi14').val() == null) {
        var v14 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v14 = $('#vergi14').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi15').val() == null) {
        var v15 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v15 = $('#vergi15').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi16').val() == null) {
        var v16 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v16 = $('#vergi16').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi17').val() == null) {
        var v17 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v17 = $('#vergi17').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi18').val() == null) {
        var v18 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v18 = $('#vergi18').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi19').val() == null) {
        var v19 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v19 = $('#vergi19').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi20').val() == null) {
        var v20 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v20 = $('#vergi20').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi21').val() == null) {
        var v21 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v21 = $('#vergi21').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi22').val() == null) {
        var v22 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v22 = $('#vergi22').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi23').val() == null) {
        var v23 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v23 = $('#vergi23').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi24').val() == null) {
        var v24 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v24 = $('#vergi24').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi25').val() == null) {
        var v25 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v25 = $('#vergi25').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi26').val() == null) {
        var v26 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v26 = $('#vergi26').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi27').val() == null) {
        var v27 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v27 = $('#vergi27').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi28').val() == null) {
        var v28 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v28 = $('#vergi28').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi29').val() == null) {
        var v29 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v29 = $('#vergi29').val();
    }
    if ($('#vergi30').val() == null) {
        var v30 = 0;
    }
    else {
        var v30 = $('#vergi30').val();
    }
    var vergiler;
    vergiler = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(v)+accounting.unformat(v1)+accounting.unformat(v2)+accounting.unformat(v3)+accounting.unformat(v4)+accounting.unformat(v5)+accounting.unformat(v6)+accounting.unformat(v7)+accounting.unformat(v8)+accounting.unformat(v9)+accounting.unformat(v10)+accounting.unformat(v11)+accounting.unformat(v12)+accounting.unformat(v13)+accounting.unformat(v14)+accounting.unformat(v15)+accounting.unformat(v16)+accounting.unformat(v17)+accounting.unformat(v18)+accounting.unformat(v19)+accounting.unformat(v20)+accounting.unformat(v21)+accounting.unformat(v22)+accounting.unformat(v23)+accounting.unformat(v24)+accounting.unformat(v25)+accounting.unformat(v26)+accounting.unformat(v27)+accounting.unformat(v28)+accounting.unformat(v29)+accounting.unformat(v30));
    document.urunformu.toplam1.value = accounting.formatMoney(document.urunformu.adet1.value*document.urunformu.birimfiyat1.value)
    document.urunformu.vergi1.value = accounting.formatMoney(document.urunformu.adet1.value*document.urunformu.birimfiyat1.value*document.urunformu.vergioran1.value/100)
    $('#topkdv').html(""+vergiler +"");
    $('#yekun').html(""+sonuc +"");
    document.getElementById("geneltoplam").innerHTML = accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat(document.getElementById("yekun").innerHTML)+accounting.unformat(document.getElementById("topkdv").innerHTML))
}

//note: function inputkopyala2,3,4... continues to 29
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_more" class="dt-button buttons-print btn btn-cerceve btn-xs ml">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Add New</b>
</a>        

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var maxAppend = 0;
        var degisken = 1;
        $("#add_more").click(function () {
            if (maxAppend >= 29) {
                alert("Maksimum Satır Sayısına Ulaştınız");
            }
            else {
                var add_new = $('<tr style=""><td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" required  placeholder="Ürün Adı" class="form-control"></td>\n\
                        <td><textarea style="height:40px;" rows="1" name="item_desc[]" placeholder="Ürün Açıklaması" class="form-control"></textarea></td>\n\
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><input onkeyup="inputkopyala' +degisken+ '()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="adet' +degisken+ '" type="text" data-parsley-type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="1" required class="form-control"></td>">\n\
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><input onkeyup="inputkopyala' +degisken+ '()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="birimfiyat' +degisken+ '" type="text" data-parsley-type="number" name="unit_cost[]" required placeholder="100 ₺" class="form-control"></td>\n\
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><select onchange="inputkopyala' +degisken+ '()" id="vergioran' +degisken+ '" name="item_tax_rate[]" class="form-control"><option value="0.00"><?= lang('none') ?></option>\n\\n\
            <?php
                $tax_rates = $this->db->get('tbl_tax_rates')->result();
                if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
                    foreach ($tax_rates as $v_tax) {
                    ?><option value="<?= $v_tax->tax_rate_percent ?>"><?= $v_tax->tax_rate_name ?></option><?php
                    }
                }
                ?></select></td>\n\
<td class="col-sm-1"><input id="vergi' +degisken+ '" type="text" name="tax" placeholder="0,00 ₺" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>\n\
<td class="col-sm-2"><input id="toplam' +degisken+ '" type="text" value="" name="tax" placeholder="0,00 ₺" readonly="" class="form-control toplam"></td>\n\
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF dt-button buttons-print btn btn-cerceve btn-xs mr"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></strong></td></tr>\n<br/>');
                degisken++;
                maxAppend++;
                $("#add_new").append(add_new);
            }
        });

        $("#add_new").on('click', '.remCF', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            degisken--;
            maxAppend--;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a smaller snippet that reproduces the issue? You have errors in your syntax and there's also php code calling a database mixed in and there's this accountign thingy we don't know, so it's going to be very difficult to actually test this. Also the function `inputkopyala()` makes my eyes bleed, try using an array or something else to loop over the elements instead of writing the same lines of code like 60 times.

Comment: So many if statements all doing the same thing but for different elements :O I think you should look at using a `class` name. It will push all of those statements into one making your source code much cleaner and easier to use.